# How to ssh multiple server using loop but with two users if one fails try with another

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix, scripting

I have multiple server, I have to run particular command on all the servers.
My ssh-key is on all the servers but on few servers username is different (userme) and other servers it is root access.
I do user `ssh-agent bash` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_mykey` for root access.
I am using `for loop` to connect to multiple servers as I have stored them in a file and I am reading it through for loop.
`for i in $(cat ServersList); do echo $i ;ssh $i cat /etc/issue.net; done`
but whenever the server comes up having my username (userme) it ask for paswword.

I want to automate it, that it should take my username whenever it fails with root access.

`e.g:
for i in $(cat ServerList); do 
  echo $i; 
  ssh $i cat /etc/issue.net; 
     if (fails here) ; then
     use ssh userme@$i;
     fi;
done`

Can somebody Help me , how to do this?

Any suggestions are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` will have a non-zero exit status if it fails to connect.

```
while read i; do
  ssh "$i" cat /etc/issue.net || ssh userme@"$i" cat /etc/issue.net
done < ServerList
```

A better idea, though, would be to store the necessary user ID in the server list. For example, if the file contains

```
root host1
userme host2
userme host3
root host4
```

then your loop could get both with

```
with read user host; do
  ssh "$user@$host" cat /etc/issue.net
done < ServerList
```

Comment: It would be much more time consuming to enter username in list of servers as list is quit big.
Thanks for the suggestion any ways ...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the || operator as shown below:

```
for i in $(cat ServerList); do 
  echo $i; 
  ssh $i cat /etc/issue.net || ssh userme@$i cat /etc/issue.net; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is still asking for password and after hitting return key thrice, it is switching to another user.

Comment: Please refer to http://serverfault.com/questions/61915/how-do-i-make-ssh-fail-rather-than-prompt-for-a-password-if-the-public-key-authe to prevent ssh from prompting password if authentication fails. It depends on which ssh client you are using.

Comment: Probably adding **-oBatchMode=yes** to your ssh command should help you to suppress password prompts.